# Error ''segmentation fault core dumped'' in C

Tags: c, lógica

Sou meio novato ainda mas ainda não consegui resolver tal problema, por isso vim recorrer aqui.
Utilizo o linux e estou com um problema no código que eu fiz (é bem simples).

O código lê um número e transforma em uma letra(pelo menos era para acontecer isto) mas está apresentando o seguinte erro no final: `segmentation fault core dumped`.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <locale.h>

char nome [20];

int num;

void main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, ("Portuguese"));

    printf(" \t\tLETRA DO ALFABETO\n ");
    printf(" \n\nOlá, digite aqui seu nome: ");
    fgets (nome, sizeof (nome), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

        system("clear");


    printf(" \n\nOlá %s,digite aqui o número para saber qua letra ele representa: ",nome);
    scanf("%d", &num);

        system("clear");

    printf("\n\n %s, o número %d representa a letra %s\n\n",nome,num,(char)num);



return 0;

}
```

se tiverem alguma sugestão para melhora do código, aceito também.

Comment: Na função printf utilize `%c` no lugar do `%s` final para exibir a letra.

Comment: Já tentei, mas não sai nada, fica vazio o local.

Comment: Em meu teste, utilizando `%c`, funcionou perfeitamente. Certifique-se de fornecer para `num` um valor que corresponda a um caractere imprimível da tabela ASCII (letras minúsculas: de 97 a 122.letras maiúsculas: de 41 a 90, outros caracteres imprimíveis: vide tabela ASCII).

Comment: Acho que consegui resolver com sua dica, realmente estava colocando números errôneos para transformar. Mt obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trocar %s por %c deve resolver o problema visto que você está tentando imprimir
um único caractere e não uma string, como já mencionado pelo pessoal.
Certifique-se apenas de informar um valor válido da tabela ASCII (lembrando que
os caracteres de 0 a 31 não podem ser impressos).

Como sugestões de melhoria eu mudaria void main para int main(), já que você
está retornando 0 no final do programa (ou então remover o return 0), remover as
chamadas à função system("clear") caso não sejam necessárias, porque são
dependentes de plataforma (esse código não funcionaria em windows, por exemplo,
que usa o comando cls),usar fgets para ler o inteiro, assim você não precisaria
mais da função fflush() (mas para isso você teria que converter uma string em
inteiro usando a função atoi, por exemplo), definir uma macro com o tamanho
máximo da string (facilitando alterar o tamanho dela posteriormente), colocar as
variáveis nome e num dentro da função main e remover a quebra de linha no final
da string retornada pelo fgets, assim o programa não pula uma linha depois de escrever o nome.

Segue o código com as melhorias sugeridas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h> // para usar a função strlen()

#define TAMANHO_STR 20

int main()
{
    char nome[TAMANHO_STR+1];
    char num_str[TAMANHO_STR+1];
    int num;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, ("Portuguese"));

    printf("\t\tLETRA DO ALFABETO\n ");
    printf("\n\nOlá, digite aqui seu nome: ");
    fgets(nome, TAMANHO_STR+1, stdin);

    int l = strlen(nome); // descobre o comprimento da string
    if (l > 0 && nome[l-1] == '\n') // se a string não é vazia e o último caractere é \n
        nome[l-1] = 0; // define último caractere como \0

    printf(" \n\nOlá %s, digite aqui o número para saber qua letra ele representa: ",nome);

    fgets(num_str, TAMANHO_STR+1, stdin);
    num = atoi(num_str);

    printf("\n\n%s, o número %d representa a letra %c\n\n", nome, num, (char) num);

    return 0;
}
```

Note que o último caractere de toda string em C é \0, por isso defini o tamanho das strings como TAMANHO_STR+1 e substituí o penúltimo caractere por \0.

Edit: Como bem lembrado por um comentário aqui, esqueci de explicar que a função `fgets` salva na string o caractere de quebra de linha `\n`, se couber. Ou seja, se você digitar como entrada `abc` a string receberá `abc\n\0` (caso a string tenha 5 ou mais caracteres neste exemplo). Para remover isso, o programa encontra o penúltimo caractere e o altera para `\0`, assim a string pode ser impressa sem a quebra de linha.

Comment: Você apenas se esqueceu de alertar que utilizando a função `fgets` com a string lida tendo menos caracteres que o máximo especificado na função então o caractere '\n' final também será incorporado à string lida e para efeitos práticos ele deve ser removido ou substituido pelo caractere terminador '\0'.

Comment: Mas eu disse: "... com a string lida tendo menos caracteres que o máximo especificado na função então o caractere '\n' final também será incorporado à string lida ..."

Comment: Mil desculpas, li errado o comentário. De fato, faltou mencionar isso. Muito obrigado pela sugestão, já vou editar a resposta e incluir isso :)